# V8-like Hashtable for C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js, dictionary, v8

I'm programming an apartment & house rental site. Since there are never more than 10'000 properties for rent, it's no problem to load em all into memory. Now, when a users want to search for a specific one, he can define very much filters for price, room, escalator etc.

Every property has a very different set of attributes. One property may have an attribute that another property does not have. So, creating a Class in C# that has all the attributes, while only a few of them are used is not a good idea to me. I decided to use a Dictionary instead.

A few benchmarks later, I found out, that the Dictionary is about 40 times slower in accessing attributes as a Class. I also did a benchmark for node.js, which just used objects as dictionarys. This was absolutely interesting because the exact same program in node.js performed even better than the C# example with a native class.

In fact I got the following results:

C# Dictionary: ~820ms
C# Class: ~26ms
Node.js Object: ~24ms

Each benchmark searched 1'000'000 objects by the same criterias.

I know that the Node.js version is that fast because of the V8 engine by Google. Do you know if there is a C# class that uses similar techniques as the V8 engine and gets almost the same performance?

**C# Dictionary Benchmark**

```
namespace Test {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            PropertyList p = new PropertyList();
            long startTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                p.Search();
            }
            Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now.Ticks - startTime) / 10000);
        }
    }

    class PropertyList {
        List<Property> properties = new List<Property>();
        public PropertyList() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                Property p = new Property();
                p["Strasse"] = "Oberdorfstrasse";
                p["StrassenNr"] = 6;
                p["Plz"] = 6277;
                p["Ort"] = "Lieli";
                p["Preis"] = 600;
                p["Fläche"] = 70;
                p["Zimmer"] = 2;
                p["Lift"] = true;
                p["Verfügbarkeit"] = 7;
                p["Keller"] = false;
                p["Neubau"] = true;
                p["ÖV"] = false;

                properties.Add(p);
            }
        }
        public void Search() {
            int found = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++) {
                Property p = properties[i];
                if ((string)p["Strasse"] == "Oberdorfstrasse" &&
                   (int)p["StrassenNr"] == 6 &&
                   (int)p["Plz"] == 6277 &&
                   (string)p["Ort"] == "Lieli" &&
                   (int)p["Preis"] >= 500 && (int)p["Preis"] <= 1000 &&
                   (int)p["Fläche"] >= 10 && (int)p["Fläche"] <= 200 &&
                   (int)p["Zimmer"] == 2 &&
                   (bool)p["Lift"] == true &&
                   (int)p["Verfügbarkeit"] >= 2 && (int)p["Verfügbarkeit"] <= 8 &&
                   (bool)p["Keller"] == false &&
                   (bool)p["Neubau"] == true &&
                   (bool)p["ÖV"] == true
                ) {
                    found++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Property {
        private Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public object this[string key] {
            get {
                return values[key];
            }
            set {
                values[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**C# Class Benchmark**

```
namespace Test {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            SpecificPropertyList p2 = new SpecificPropertyList();

            long startTime2 = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                p2.Search();
            }

            Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now.Ticks - startTime2) / 10000);

        }
    }

    class SpecificPropertyList {
        List<SpecificProperty> properties = new List<SpecificProperty>();
        public SpecificPropertyList() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                SpecificProperty p = new SpecificProperty();
                p.Strasse = "Oberdorfstrasse";
                p.StrassenNr = 6;
                p.Plz = 6277;
                p.Ort = "Lieli";
                p.Preis = 600;
                p.Fläche = 70;
                p.Zimmer = 2;
                p.Lift = true;
                p.Verfügbarkeit = 7;
                p.Keller = false;
                p.Neubau = true;
                p.ÖV = false;

                properties.Add(p);
            }
        }
        public void Search() {
            int found = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++) {
                SpecificProperty p = properties[i];
                if (p.Strasse == "Oberdorfstrasse" &&
                   p.StrassenNr == 6 &&
                   p.Plz == 6277 &&
                   p.Ort == "Lieli" &&
                   p.Preis >= 500 && p.Preis <= 1000 &&
                   p.Fläche >= 10 && p.Fläche <= 200 &&
                   p.Zimmer == 2 &&
                   p.Lift == true &&
                   p.Verfügbarkeit >= 2 && p.Verfügbarkeit <= 8 &&
                   p.Keller == false &&
                   p.Neubau == true &&
                   p.ÖV == true
                ) {
                    found++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class SpecificProperty {
        public string Strasse;
        public int StrassenNr;
        public int Plz;
        public string Ort;
        public int Preis;
        public int Fläche;
        public int Zimmer;
        public bool Lift;
        public int Verfügbarkeit;
        public bool Keller;
        public bool Neubau;
        public bool ÖV;
    }
}
```

**Node.js Benchmark**

```
var properties = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    var p = {
        Strasse:"Oberdorfstrasse",
        StrassenNr:6,
        Plz:6277,
        Ort:"Lieli",
        Preis:600,
        Fläche:70,
        Zimmer:2,
        Lift:true,
        Verfügbarkeit:7,
        Keller:false,
        Neubau:true,
        ÖV:false
    };
    properties.push(p);
}



function search(){
    var found = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){
        var p = properties[i];
        if(p.Strasse == "Oberdorfstrasse" && p.StrassenNr == 6 && p.Plz == 6277 && p.Ort == "Lieli" &&
            p.Preis >= 500 && p.Preis <= 1000 &&
            p.Fläche>= 10 && p.Fläche <= 100 &&
            p.Zimmer == 2 &&
            p.Verfügbarkeit >= 2 && p.Verfügbarkeit <= 8 &&
            p.Keller == false && p.Neubau == true && p.ÖV == false
        ){
            found++;
        }
    }
}
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    search();
}
console.log(new Date().getTime()-startTime);
```

Comment: was your c# test in 'Release' mode?

Comment: It would be interesting to see both your C# and JavaScript code.

Comment: It is likely that your code is flawed because the result is very unlikely. Please show it to us.

Comment: @Adrian oh, well, no! Running it in Release mode was a bit faster but was still not as fast as node.js. I updated the times in the post.

Comment: You could also try to use the ExpandoObject in your C#. That way you could probably make a pretty straight forward port of the JavaScript code. Just to make sure you aren't benchmarking different things.

Comment: So, I posted the benchmark code now so you all can see it ;)

Comment: And you're not running the code under the debugger, right? (Ctrl+F5, *not* just F5)

Comment: Have you ever read [Examination of Data Structures Using C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379570(v=vs.80).aspx) not so up to date but data structure never change too much. BST may fit your need.

Comment: I think you could make the C# code faster by using Enum as a key instead of a string.

Comment: @OndraMorský Thanks for that idea! It halved the executing times for the Dictionary benchmark to ~440ms. But using enums, the code would automatically get less dynamic...

Comment: @VanCoding The code is not less dynamic. It is only a lot more complex: Create an enum type and define attributes you need. You can then generate the UI from this enum type. UI will know what is the datatype of every field (from attributes of enum). The user will click the filter and you search engine will then do very simple comparison of user filter and object values.

Comment: Another idea: You can make it faster with parallel processing - Parallel.For, PLING or similar.

Comment: @OndraMorský It is less dynamic because I can't add a new attribute without recompiling the program. I think it really would be a better idea to use integer keys like usr mentioned it.

Comment: If you are planning to make a library than you are right, but normal website is usually compiled automatically on the first visit. I don´t think integers are good idea. If you get back to your code after one week you will not know what is eg. number 17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the reason for C# being slower is that V8 is optimized for exactly this scenario (lots of dictionaries having exactly the same members).

You are kind of misusing C# here. Instead of a dictionary, just use a normal class with auto-properties. C# will be much faster then, even faster than V8 (because you are playing to its strength and not to its weakness).

And that is why your "specific object" benchmark is the fastest.

Comment: You're probably right, but still, the node.js objects are dynamic while the C# ones are not. I really cant create a class for every possible property a user wants to add. So I would have to use a class that has all the attributes a user can define. I guess this would lead to memory problems... I don't care about the performance difference between tose two benachmarks that much, but since the node.js one is much more flexible I need some alternative in C#.

Comment: How many properties are there? Less than 100? Define a property for each. Less than 1000? Assign each one an index and store the property values in an object[] (each property has a fixed index).

Comment: Also, string keys are much more expensive than integer keys due to hashing. Can you use integer keys?

Comment: And: Your V8 benchmark is flawed: It will become *much* slower when you actually give each object different properties. V8 optimized heavily for the case that the properties are exactly the same. Plan for 100x slowdown.

Comment: Your idea with the property indices is not bad. I'll try to do another benchmark using this. I also tested the "every property is of another class"-theory and it's true. Adding the line `p[new Date()+""+Math.random()] = 8;` below `properties.push(p);` will change the executing time to ~104ms. No matther how many different attributes I add, this time doesn't get bigger. So it's still pretty fast.

Comment: Regarding your property experiment, maybe you can add all properties with 50% probability to really get V8 off track. Like this: if(rand() < 0.5) myObj.Preis = 1234; I guess V8 is still optimizing for the properties which are always the same (most of them). You really need to use real test data here because V8 has many special cases for real-world usage.

Comment: I did it like you mentioned. Every property with a 50% probability. Result: 100-115ms. It indeed varies a bit.

Comment: V8 is impressive! Just for fun I implemented the same in Ruby and it ran for about 1800ms... https://gist.github.com/2819303